# Was bedeutet es, wenn ein Satz mit "Zur Sicherheit" eingeleitet wird?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Es geht mir konkret um folgendes Satzfragment welches für die Bedingungen einer Weihnachtsaktion in einem Online-Shop verwendet wurde:

> - zur Sicherheit in die Bestellbemerkung "Zusammenfassen" schreiben

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach machen die Worte "zur Sicherheit" aus einem "muss" ein "kann".

In meinem konkreten Fall habe ich die Bestellbemerkung "Zusammenfassen" für zwei Sammelbestellungen weggelassen. Durch das "spätere Lieferdatum" war m.E. bereits klar, dass es sich um eine Sammelbestellung handeln muss.

Der Händler sieht das anders. Er hat mir mit jeweils einem Tag Abstand zwei Lieferungen geschickt und für beide Versandkosten berechnet. Wäre die Bestellungen zusammengefasst worden, dann wären keine Versandkosten angefallen.

Verstehe ich "zur Sicherheit ..." falsch?

---

**Edit:** Der gesamte Text der Bedingungen lautete wie folgt:

> Wie kann ich Bestellungen aus dem Weihnachtskalender sammeln?
> Bestell das Spiel ganz normal, wie du es gewohnt bist. Im Bestellabschluss müssen folgende Bedingungen erfüllt sein:
>
> - alle gesammelten Bestellungen haben die gleiche Zahlart
> - du wählst ein späteres Lieferdatum, bis zu dem du sammeln willst (Häkchen setzen bei "später ausliefern" und Datum eingeben) (max. 10 Tage nach Aktionsende). Tipp: Zu Weihnachten ist viel los. Sollen es Geschenke werden, wähle das Datum nicht zu knappt vorm Fest!
> - zur Sicherheit in die Bestellbemerkung "Zusammenfassen" schreiben
> - bei Vorauszahlungen (Vorkasse, Paypal, Sofortüberweisung, Kreditkarte, Barzahlen) muss die Zahlung innerhalb von 3 Werktagen bei uns eingehen, da die Bestellung sonst vom System storniert und die Reservierung der Artikel aufgehoben wird.
>
> WICHTIG: Nur wenn ALLE diese Bedingungen erfüllt sind, klappt das Sammeln!

---

Edit 2, ursprünglich in eigener Antwort platziert:

"Zur Sicherheit" scheint keine eindeutige Bedeutung zu haben. Ich habe diese Floskel bisher immer als eine Art "optional aber empfehlenswert" verstanden.

Dieses Verständnis wird nicht universell geteilt. Insbesondere gibt es das Sprachverständnis, dass eine Anweisung, die mit "Zur Sicherheit" eingeleitet wird nicht optional ist. Es scheint sogar das Verständnis zu geben, dass hierdurch einer obligatorischen Anweisung zusätzlicher Nachdruck verliehen wird.

Das hat mich überrascht und ich bedanke mich an allen Personen, die Antworten oder Kommentare hinterlassen haben.

Eingangs war ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass der Händler seine eigenen Bedingungen nicht verstanden hat. Inzwischen denke ich, dass wir ein unterschiedliches Verständnis dieser Floskel haben.

Es wäre interessant zu erörtern, wie diese unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen zustande kommen, aber das ist eine komplett andere Fragestellung.

Ich will abschließend nur festhalten, dass diese Floskel aufgrund der unterschiedlichen Interpretationen, innerhalb eines Kaufvertrags (o.Ä.) nichts verloren hat.

Ich habe den geforderten Betrag inkl. Mahnung inzwischen bezahlt. Dennoch sehe den Händler in der Pflicht bei zukünftigen Aktionen seine Bedingungen klarer zu formulieren und solche mehrdeutigen Floskeln zu unterlassen.

Comment: Ich würde es auch als "kann" statt "muss" verstehen, aber gleichzeitig auch als "ansonsten keine Garantie, dass es klappt". (Bzw. _kann_ klappen, _muss_ aber nicht.)

In dem Zusammenhang empfinde ich es aber auch als eine seltsame Formulierung. Es wäre wohl unmißverständlicher und sinnvoller, die Angabe zwingend zu verlangen, statt dem Kunden eine für ihn nicht überschaubare Risikoabwägung anzubieten.

Comment: Sorry, wenn ich das so deutlich anspreche, aber Du machst in Deinen zahlreichen, über den Thread verteilten Kommentaren den Eindruck, als würdest Du von uns erwarten, Dir zu bestätigen, daß Du ohnehin alles richtig gemacht hast und nur der Händler Schuld daran hat, daß Du Porto bezahlen mußtest. Dafür ist das hier das falsche Forum, denn hier beschäftigt man sich mit Sprache, nicht mit dem Versandhandel und schon gar nicht mit den Auswirkungen selbstverschuldeter Unterlassungen.

Comment: Ich habe nur Fragen beantwortet und versucht mehr Kontext zu liefern. Mein Verständnis von "Zur Sicherheit" entsprach dem von planetmaker. So wie du @bakunin das schreibst, würde ja sogar das genaue Gegenteil ausgesagt werden. Ich nehme für mich mit, dass es keine einheitliche Interpretation dieser Floskel gibt.

Comment: @bikeshedder: nein, so weit sind planetmaker und ich gar nicht auseinander: "zur Sicherheit" ist sicher *kein verpflichtendes Element*, aber wer es wegläßt, der muß halt auch mit den Konsequenzen (hier: Zustellgebühren) leben. Wer diese *sicher* vermeiden will, muß das tun, was nach *zur Sicherheit* eben steht.

Answer (score 2):

Ausschlaggebend ist hier vor allem die letzte Anweisung:

> WICHTIG: Nur wenn ALLE diese Bedingungen erfüllt sind, klappt das Sammeln!

Eine der geforderten Bedingungen ist diese:

> in die Bestellbemerkung "Zusammenfassen" schreiben

Dass davor die Floskel »zur Sicherheit« steht, bedeutet nur, dass sich der Händler bei Vorliegen der anderen Bedingungen bemühen wird, Bestellungen zu sammeln. Aber es wird nicht garanitert, dass das dann auch immer klappt. Nur wenn man noch ausdrücklich das geforderte Wort *»Zusammenfassen«* in das entsprechende Feld schreibt, wird versprochen, den Wunsch zu erfüllen. Ohne dieses Wort wird daraus ein Lotteriespiel.

Comment: Würde sich nach dieser Interpretation irgend etwas an der Bedeutung ändern, wenn die Worte "Zur Sicherheit" weggelassen werden?

Comment: @bikeshedder: Ja. Wenn der Händler diese beiden Worte weglässt und du das Wort "Zusammenfassen" nicht in die Bestellbemerkung schreibst, dann wird der Händler sich nicht bemühen, Bestellungen trotzdem zu sammeln. Dann hast du also die Sicherheit, dass es nicht klappen wird. So, wie du den Fall beschrieben hast, hätte es ja auch sein können, dass der Händler deine Bestellungen trotzdem sammelt. Aber wenn du das Zauberwort nicht verwendest, ist das eben etwas zufälliges.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist schon sehr dünnes Eis. Eine Begründung liefert die Frage nicht, mutet nach reinem Wunschdenken an.

Der Lieferant sieht das halt ebenso pragmatisch, bzw. sieht er es eben nicht, und so wird aus dem Fehlen des Vermerks ein *kann*.

Als einfaches Beispiel, meine Mutter hat immer gesagt, "Räum bitte dein Zimmer auf" oder ähnliches, was ich für eine Kannbestimmung hielt, und dann hieß es ab und zu noch in dringlichem Tonfall, "das war keine Bitte"; vergleich übrigens *Gebot* wie *Geschwindigkeitsgebot*, und medium *weil der Anstand es gebietet*.

Also handelt es sich meiner Auffassung nach um eine Höflichkeitsform, der dringend Folge zu leisten ist. Um das anzuzweifeln, müsste man schon Zweifel an der Zulässigkeit der allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen erheben, die Formulierung sei entgegen Treu und Glauben absichtlich irreführend gewesen. Ansonsten gilt, dass Verträge nicht nach dem Wortlaut sondern nach dem Sinn und Zweck auszulegen sind, laut bürgerlichem Gesetzbuch.

Answer (score 1):

"Zur Sicherheit..." steht in solchen Kontexten häufig, wenn die beschriebene Aktion garantiert, dass es auch gemäß Wunsch stattfinden kann und umgekehrt Fehler wahrscheinlich(er) sind, wenn diese Aktion weggelassen wird. Im Englischen könnte man mit "to make sure..." oder sogar eher als "Please indicate..." formulieren.

Ein "zur Sicherheit" ist sicher kein verpflichtendes Element, aber ein empfohlenes, je nach Kontext auch deutlich stärker als "kann"; hier lese ich es eher als ein freundliches "Falls Sie weniger Versandkosten zahlen wollen, tun sie das:..." - denn die Bestellung wird ja jeweils einzeln bearbeitet, kostet aber sonst in Summe mehr.

Im konkreten Kontext - und das hat mit Sprache jetzt nichts mehr zu tun - wird der Händler ziemlich sicher jede Bestellung einzeln abarbeiten und nicht jedes Mal gucken, ob der gleiche Kunde noch weitere Bestellungen hat. Das heißt ohne Hinweis auf andere Bestellungen, die mit der gerade bearbeiteten zusammengefasst werden sollen, wird jede Bestellung einzeln abgefertigt.

Comment: Es ist eher kein "kann", auch kein "soll" als ein "du willst eigentlich".

Comment: Es gab noch ein weiteres Merkmal durch welches die Bestellungen zusammengefasst werden konnten. Das ist in meinem Fall auch passiert. Nur leider in Form von zwei Teillieferungen, die dann Versandkosten verursacht haben. Ich habe die Frage aktualisiert und den Text mit den Bedingungen angehängt.

Comment: Dort steht auch "Nur wenn ALLE ...". Ein spätere Lieferdatum bedeutet nicht automatisch, dass noch etwas dazu kommen soll. Und was meinst Du damit, dass die Bestellungen zu zwei Teillieferungen zusammengefasst wurden? Viel viele Bestellungen?

Comment: Ich habe zwei Bestellungen aufgegeben mit gleichem "spätere Lieferdatum" (24.12.2023). Da dieser Termin eh auf die Feiertage fiel, hat der Händler ein paar Tage später eine erste Teillieferung (28.12.) gemacht und einen Tag später (29.12.) den letzten fehlenden Artikel als zweite Teillieferung versendet. Die Lieferungen bestanden jeweils aus Teilen beider Bestellungen. d.h. die beiden Bestellungen wurden zusammengefasst, aber als zwei Teillieferungen versendet.

Comment: Wenn er die einzelnen Bestellungen gesplittet hat,sollten dadurch keine höheren Versandkosten entstehen, unabhängig von der Bestellbemerkung.

Comment: Beide Bestellungen lagen unter dem "Mindestbestellwert" (d.h. es wären Versandkosten angefallen). Nur zusammen und mit allen Artikeln war die Bestellung versandkostenfrei. Hintergrund: Es gab jeden Tag ein Angebot im Adventskalender und man konnte diese Angebote sammeln um Versandkosten zu sparen. Der Händler hält mir nun vor, dass die fehlende Bemerkung "Teillieferung" daran schuld ist und ich für die Versandkosten aufkommen muss.

Answer (score 1):

So, wie ich das verstehe, ist die Anweisung eigentlich klar:

> - zur Sicherheit in die Bestellbemerkung "Zusammenfassen" schreiben

Ich verstehe das als Anweisung, die in jedem Fall auszuführen ist. Das "zur Sicherheit" macht die Anweisung nicht optional, sondern dient als Erklärung, warum das Wort "zusammenfassen" überhaupt hingeschrieben werden soll. Nämlich als Hinweis für den Lieferanten, für den Fall, daß der das nicht von sich aus macht.

"Zur Sicherheit" bedeutet also nicht, man kann das auch noch dazuschreiben, wenn man ganz sichergehen will, sondern, das ist auf jeden Fall dazuzuschreiben, damit sichergestellt ist, daß der Lieferant die Bestellung so erledigt, wie man das haben möchte.

Comment: Gerade im Zusammenhang mit der Warnung "WICHTIG: Nur wenn ALLE diese Bedingungen erfüllt sind, klappt das Sammeln!" sehe ich das auch so. Ja, es könnte unter Umständen vielleicht auch ohne zufällig mal funktionieren, aber für den Kunden ist der Punkt obligatorisch, wenn es klappen soll.

Comment: Ich verstehe den letzten Absatz nicht. Leicht umformuliert: Es bedeutet also _nicht_: "Wenn man es dazuschreibt, ist X sichergestellt." Sondern es bedeutet: "Wenn man es dazuschreibt, ist X sichergestellt." Ich sehe den Unterschied nicht, den du durch das "sondern" darzustellen versuchst.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Der Unterschied wird durch "man kann ..." bzw. "das ist dazuzuschreiben" ausgedrückt. Letzteres bedeutet so viel wie "das muß dazugeschrieben werden". Der Unterschied ist also der zwischen "man kann" und "man muß".